# About Store current date and time in logout field

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This query

```
SELECT * FROM login_history WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY login_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

shows me today's date and time.

I want to show yesterday date and time. How should I write modify it?

Comment: why would you want it to show yesterday? what if the user did logged in today?

Comment: What is ur goal ?

Comment: actually, sir, I have multiple entries of users and each user can be shown own last login time. because of 5 working days and 2 holidays in one week then if the user can login Sunday then he shows the current entry or today's entry. I would like to show their last activity or previous login time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want yesterday login:

```
SELECT * FROM login_history WHERE user_id = 1 WHERE login_date BETWEEN SUBDATE( CURDATE( ) , 1 ) AND CURDATE( ) ORDER BY login_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

If you want previous login:

```
SELECT * FROM login_history WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY login_date DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: Thank You, sir, it's a perfect solution for me.